# Jquery mobile device rotation shrinks the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

So I am having an issue with JQM and device rotation on the iOS products.  When the user spins the screen, it doesn't resize to fill.  I have this line in the head which handles the display size:

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height,width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0" >
```

Does anyone know why the iPhones are not handling the screen rotation properly?  It works fine on my android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out lol.

in my head, I was doing this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height,width=device-width,initial scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0" >
```

to this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Boneheaded mistake.  Hopefully that helps some of you guys out.

Comment: To scale properly for all device screen sizes you should add `width=device-width` to your new `viewport` tag.

Comment: Will that break the rotation on the iPhone?  That's where I was finding the problem...

Comment: I had this issue a while back and I use this `viewport` tag: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0" >`. I found that by removing the `height=device-height` that orientation changes happen as expected. I also found that if you have `height=device-height` in your `viewport` tag that you can fix the iOS orientation-change problem by switching the height/width values in the `viewport` tag on `orientationchange`.