# Stop rotate on mobile device

Tags: android, ios, web-applications, jquery-mobile, mobile

This question has been asked many times on stackoverflow, but each time the correct answer was not working or not the correct one.

I am reopening this question, due to it's importance for mobile web device programmers.

I want to be able to stop rotation on a *WEB SITE* on a browser on one of the following OS: IOS and/or Android device  or at least to modify the rotation to last landscape at least. So only landscape is permitted as a rotation.

I have tried many related questions with no solution:

- [Blocking device rotation on mobile web pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501510/blocking-device-rotation-on-mobile-web-pages)
- [Jquery mobile device rotation shrinks the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104233/jquery-mobile-device-rotation-shrinks-the-screen)

Any idea is welcome, thank you.

p.s.

Comment: So your question is how to define what orientations are valid in an iOS App?

Comment: How about this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207008/how-do-i-lock-the-orientation-to-portrait-mode-in-a-iphone-web-application

Comment: Please allow visitors to your Web site to use their device in whatever orientation they want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@CommonsWare is right, you shouldn't just block the user from being able to rotate their device however they want. In fact, that's what makes mobile web apps so versatile. They encompass the principals of responsive design.

I know this isn't the answer you're really looking for but if you insist on doing so, take a look here: [Block mobile web rotation with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501510/blocking-device-rotation-on-mobile-web-pages).
I'm not sure but I'm guessing that still won't work simply because a web app isn't native to whatever device you're viewing it on and the app you're actually in is a browser eg Chrome, Safari, ect and those are almost certainly going to have different orientations enabled regardless of what your web app is doing.

Comment: the link you provided, it the one I mentioned in the question that  I have tried and didn't work for me.

Comment: Ah sorry didn't realize that. Well all I can say is that it's more likely not, not possible.

Comment: There are use cases where you would want a webpage to stay in a certain orientation. For instance, if a html5 web game was designed to use orientation to change direction. You want the graphics/page itself to stay in the same direction with no rotation animation as it would them be a jarring jump in the game you may not want.